# WASAPI stream attenuation on non-communication devices - should it work?

Tags: c++, windows, sip, wasapi

I have build custom SIP/RTP softphone which uses WASAPI for audio input / output.
Windows 10 is lowering other audio streams volume when call comes and restores it back when call is finished. I know this is called "stream-attenuation" or "audio ducking" according to MSDN.

However all of this works only on communication device; the volume is not lowered on another audio devices which play background audio in this moment.

MSDN does not explain this explicitly and I don't understand. Is it normal behavior ?
Or audio streams volume should be lowered on all other audio devices as well ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/handling-audio-ducking-events-from-communication-devices

Comment: Dear Hans, I've read the article. However I don't see there an answer for my question.